# https:// access using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, https, qnetworkaccessmanager, tls-psk

I've been trying to load a(ny) https:// webpage using QNetworkAccessManager, but can't get past the: preSharedKeyAuthenticationRequired(QSslPreSharedKeyAuthenticator *) signal.  When I load the same pages with http:// they come in fine, but some servers require https:// so I'm stuck with them.

Edit to add: this is on Ubuntu 18.04 with Qt 5.9.5

I've connected most of the error signals, those aren't being emitted - I just get the encrypted() and preSharedKeyAuthenticationRequired() signals, which are pretty self explanatory as to what is happening, but the documentation for how to move forward is... lacking.

All these https:// pages load easily/simply in Chrome - no passwords required.

How can I make QNetworkAccessManager pull the pages the way that Chrome does, or similarly?

```
PageHandler::PageHandler( QObject *parent ) : QObject(parent)
{ connect(&networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)) , SLOT(pageRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*))  );
  connect(&networkManager, SIGNAL(encrypted(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(pageRequestEncrypted(QNetworkReply*)) );
  connect(&networkManager, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)), SLOT(sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)) );
  getPage( QUrl( "https://google.com/" ) );
}

void  PageHandler::getPage( const QUrl &url )
{ QNetworkRequest *request = new QNetworkRequest();
//  request.setSslConfiguration( QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration() ); this seems to do nothing
  request->setHeader( QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader, APP_NAME );
  request->setUrl( url );
  QNetworkReply *r = networkManager.get( *request );
  connect( r, SIGNAL(finished()),  SLOT(replyFinished())  );
  connect( r, SIGNAL(encrypted()), SLOT(replyEncrypted()) );
  connect( r, SIGNAL(preSharedKeyAuthenticationRequired(QSslPreSharedKeyAuthenticator *)), SLOT(preSharedKeyAuthenticationRequired(QSslPreSharedKeyAuthenticator *)) );
//  connect( r, SIGNAL(errorOccurred(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), SLOT(errorOccurred(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)) );  Qt 5.15+ only
  qDebug( QString( "getting page %1" ).arg( url.toString() ) );
}

// Get this for http://
void PageHandler::replyFinished()
{ qDebug( "replyFinished()" );
}

// Get this for https://
void PageHandler::replyEncrypted()
{ qDebug( "replyEncrypted()" );
}

// Never see this
void PageHandler::errorOccurred(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code)
{ qDebug( QString( "wrror occurred %1" ).arg(code) )
}

// Get this for https://
void PageHandler::preSharedKeyAuthenticationRequired( QSslPreSharedKeyAuthenticator *authenticator )
{ qDebug( QString( "preSharedKeyAuthenticationRequired hint '%1'" ).arg( QString::fromUtf8( authenticator->identityHint() ) ) ) // This is empty
  authenticator->setIdentity( QByteArray() );      // What to do here, if anything?
  authenticator->setPreSharedKey( QByteArray() );
}

// Get this for http://
void PageHandler::pageRequestFinished( QNetworkReply *r )
{ qDebug( "got page" );
  QList<QByteArray> hl = r->rawHeaderList();
  foreach ( QByteArray ba, hl )
    qDebug( QString( "header '%1'").arg( QString::fromUtf8( ba ) ) )
  qDebug( QString( "Reply '%1'").arg( QString::fromUtf8( r->readAll() ) ) )
  r->deleteLater();
}

// Get this for https:// not for http:// (as expected)
void PageHandler::encrypted( QNetworkReply *r )
{ qDebug( "encrypted" );
  if ( r->error() )
    qDebug( QString( "encrypted signal error %1 %2" ).arg( r->error() ).arg( r->errorString() ) ); // Never see this

  // Nothing shown for the header or body
  QList<QByteArray> hl = r->rawHeaderList();
  foreach ( QByteArray ba, hl )
    qDebug( QString( "Encrypted header '%1'").arg( QString::fromUtf8( ba ) ) );
  qDebug( QString( "Encrypted reply '%1'").arg( QString::fromUtf8( r->readAll() ) ) );
  // r->ignoreSslErrors();  Makes no difference if this is commented or not
  r->deleteLater();
}

void PageHandler::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *r, const QList<QSslError> &e)
{ qDebug( "sslErrors" ); // Never see this
}
```

Comment: what platform do you use? windows min-gw?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue that you have.  I could not connect to https and the problem was that I linked to the wrong version of openssl.  You can maybe check with `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#sslLibraryBuildVersionString) which is the version used to compile Qt and check if you are linking against the same version.

Comment: @apin good question Ubuntu 18.04